# Windows AppFabric - renamed server, config now not loading

Tags: powershell, appfabric

My original server was called xyz and the config was as follows:
\xyz\AppFabricConfig\ClusterConfig.xml

We renamed the server and it is now called 123, but the config is still pointing to
\xyz\AppFabricConfig\ClusterConfig.xml

And giving the following error when trying to load:

```
Use-CacheCluster : ErrorCode<ERRCMS0001>:SubStatus<ES0001>:Error while trying t
o load configuration: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Logon fai
lure: unknown user name or bad password.
 (\\xyz\AppFabricConfig\ClusterConfig.xml)
At line:1 char:62
+ Import-Module DistributedCacheAdministration;Use-CacheCluster <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Use-CacheCluster], DataCacheE
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ERRCMS0001,Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.C
   ommands.UseCacheClusterCommand
```

I've manually edited the following file:
C:\Windows\System32\AppFabric\DistributedCacheService.exe.config

And set: configuration/dataCacheConfig/clusterConfig connectionString="\123\AppFabricConfig\ClusterConfig.xml"

But its still trying to load from:
\xyz\AppFabricConfig\ClusterConfig.xml

Stumped - close to re-installing, but would really prefer not too!

Comment: Silly me - forgot all about the Windows Server AppFabric Configuration Wizard ... that allowed me to reset it.

Comment: @downathone Only thing with the wizard is it seems to require escalated privileges when using a SQL Database store. Changing the registry entry works perfectly if it's just changing the connection string (I also advise changing the file, even if it doesn't appear to be used, to maintain consistency), and doesn't need any other configuration changes when using SQL.

Answer (score 1):

In hind sight, best way to handle this would've been unconfigure the hosts with remove-cachehost and remove-cacheadmin, rename server and then run config wizard or run add-cachehost and add-cacheadmin.

The connection string is also present in registry, change there also: local machine\software\microsoft\appfabric\v1.0\configuration: connectionstring.

[Edit]
To remove/add the host from cluster configuration, Register-cachehost and unregister-cachehost also need to be run.

Comment: It seems to use the registry setting and not the XML config inside `C:\Windows\System32\AppFabric\DistributedCacheService.exe.config`